# How to fix "User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required., name: Path `name` is required."

Tags: node.js, nodes, validationerror

I'm a beginner who starts to learn node.js. In the middle of the way, I got a problem with a notification like this

```
{
"errors": {
    "password": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `password` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `password` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "password"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "password"
    },
    "email": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `email` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `email` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "email"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "email"
    },
    "name": {
        "name": "ValidatorError",
        "message": "Path `name` is required.",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Path `name` is required.",
            "type": "required",
            "path": "name"
        },
        "kind": "required",
        "path": "name"
    }
},
"_message": "User validation failed",
"message": "User validation failed: password: Path `password` is required., email: Path `email` is required., name: Path `name` is required."}
```

This My User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')

const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    }, 
    email: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
        minlength: 7,
        trim: true,
         validate(value){
            if (value.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
                throw new Error('Password cannot contain "password"')
            }
        }
    },
    age: {
        type: Number, 
        default: 0,
        validate(value) {
            if (value < 0 ){
                throw new Error('Age must be a positive number')
            }
        }
    }
})

module.exports = User
```

With this user route

```
const express = require('express')
require('./db/mongoose')
const User = require('./models/user')
const Task = require('./models/task')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)

    try{
        await user.save()
        res.status(201).send(user)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up on port' +port)
})
```

Does anyone understand why it would be happening?

Hope I get the answer in this forum to continue my study. Thank you in advance for your help guys. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
In my case I used this

```
app.use(express.json())
```

below

```
app.use("/users",usersController);
```

So, this cause the problem as my data is not parsing properly.

```
  const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const connect = require("./config/db");
    const usersController = require("./controller/user.controller");
    
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.use("/users",usersController);
    
    
    
    const start = async () => {
      await connect();
      app.listen(2000, async function () {
        console.log("listening on port 2000");
      });
    };
    module.exports = start;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined all these fields as required:true in your schema that's why its happening, you have to provide values to these fields i.e. while testing your api do fill these fields with some value in body.

Answer (score 0):

common mistake for this error: rechecks your input field name same as you define in schema ...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In your "Postman" before sending, change to "body" and then to "raw" module and at the end where "Text" is, change to "JSON" so your code will work.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the relevance here, sorry. The OP doesn't mention anything about postman. It appears to be a problem with the validation library in their backend.